Java error -"Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String"
There is an error showing that after using nextInt there is an error showing that it can not be converted to string
This is the code I have written
import java.util.*;
public class practics{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    String number=scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(number);
}
}

[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/hpmsc/OneDrive/Desktop/Java Programming Language/LearningJava/PracticeJava/src/practics.java",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": "16777233",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 5,
    "startColumn": 23,
    "endLineNumber": 5,
    "endColumn": 40
}]NIL


The method nextInt from Scanner returns an int type so you will need to change your number variable from String number to int number and it should work just fine.
For reference here is the javadoc for the method.

An int is not a String. And can't be implicitly converted into one. But you have at least two ways to solve this issue.
Option 1
Make it an int.
int number=scanner.nextInt(); // An `int` can be printed

Option 2
Explicitly convert the int into a String. Like,
String number=String.valueOf(scanner.nextInt());


You're using nextInt method from Scanner that returns an int. You could either change the type of number from String to int or you could use the nextLine method that returns a String value.
